# website (it has to receive latitude and longnitude data and then show it on a map like google maps or google earth )

Tags: java, c#, android, server

I have a device TK292 Tracker.The tracker has mobile internet.  In it i can specify a server where it will send latitude and longnitude data.

I would like to have a website that will receive this data and show it on a map. 
Or even if i can have my PC receive the Data and show it live in google earth or google maps would be very helpful.

Does anyone have an Idea ?

Thank you !

Regards 
Frank

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow but FYI this is not code writing service please show us some effort and then we will be glad to help you

Comment: if you can receive data(LAT,LON) on your PC then furthur you can go ahead and learn Google map API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/ or  for opensource openlayer http://openlayers.org/  but the best will be to go with Google map Api

Comment: Thank you !  I will check the google map API...  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the lat long from client and load the below page:

> http://www.latlong.net/c/?lat=39.920770&long=39.920770

replace -> lat=(latitude from android) and long=(longitude from android)!